# Unable to use call mediator in APIM 2.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I've tried this on 1.10.0 and 2.0.0

On 1.10.0, you can disable the JMS sender in repository/conf/axis2/axis2_blocking_client.xml and use the call mediator in blocking mode. This is described in this blog post: http://shenavid.blogspot.nl/2016/08/invoking-external-endpoints-using-call.html and works ok. However this method does not work in 2.0.0 even though the related issue is marked as resolved.

Has anyone else tested this on 2.0.0 already? Or found an other workaround?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <sequence name="opal_auth_and_send"
      onError="gov:apimgt/customsequences/fault/json_fault.xml"
      trace="enable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
      <property description="ORG_PAYLOAD" expression="$body/child::node()"
        name="ORG_PAYLOAD" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      <property description="URL_POSTFIX"
        expression="get-property('axis2', 'REST_URL_POSTFIX')"
        name="URL_POSTFIX" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      <property action="remove" description="Remove REST_URL_POSTFIX"
        name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2"/>
      <property action="remove" description="Remove transport headers"
        name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
      <header name="Authorization" scope="transport" value="Basic xxxxxxxx"/>
      <property description="set messageType" name="messageType"
        scope="transport" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
      <call blocking="true" description="Get Auth token (blocking)">
        <endpoint>
          <http method="get" trace="enable" uri-template="https://opal-demo34.ortec-finance.com/auth/api/token"/>
        </endpoint>
      </call>
      <property description="Get Token from Response"
        expression="json-eval($.token)" name="TOKEN" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
      <property action="remove" description="Remove transport headers"
        name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
      <log description="Log auth result" level="full"/>
      <property description="Restore REST_URL_POSTFIX"
        expression="get-property('URL_POSTFIX')" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX"
        scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
      <payloadFactory description="Restore Payload" media-type="json">
        <format>$1</format>
        <args>
          <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('ORG_PAYLOAD')"/>
        </args>
      </payloadFactory>
      <header expression="get-property('TOKEN')" name="Authorization" scope="transport"/>
    </sequence>
```

Thanks,

Danny

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I have a mediation sequence that is using the call mediator. After doing the call (in the call mediator) it returns a response, but the sequence does not continue. This was a known issue in 1.10 and should have been solved in 2.0 (based on the resolved status of APIMANAGER-4242 bug in WSO2 jira).

Comment: I have tested the scenario in 2.0.0. It works. Please update your ticket with your sequence.

Comment: Can you share the sequence? Because my scenario doesn't work. So there must be something I'm doing differently.

Comment: I did it sometime back. Don't have the sequence now. Please share yours.

Comment: I've added the sequence in the original post. It works fine on 1.10, but fails on 2.0.0. After the call mediator (and getting the response), it continues until the log mediator and then just stops... So the final call to the actual backend is not done.

Comment: Does that hangs at some point? At which mediator? can you put some more log mediators and check that? If you get the call mediator response, then this is a different issue.

Comment: It just stops after the call mediator. And I see no errors in any of the logs. I did some more testing. The API config has the same basic (production and sandbox) URL as the service called in the call mediator so `https://opal-demo34.ortec-finance.com`. However, when I replace this with an HTTP mock that emulates the backend service, the sequence just works fine. So I'm wondering if this could be related to https/ssl. But I see no SSL errors.

Comment: Can you enable synapse wire logs in log4j.properties and see how request goes? `log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG`